# I want to produce 2 pie charts in SSRS. One report on each page

Tags: ssrs-2008

[image: ![Attched are 2 pie charts I want to create in SSRS. Each on a different page][1]]I want to produce 2 pie charts in SSRS. One report on each page for each doctor.

Here is my query:

```
select booked, status, doctor from PieTest order by doctor


booked          status              doctor
------          ------              --------    
Traditional     OK                  Doe MD, John
Traditional     OK                  Doe MD, John
Online          No Show             Doe MD, John
Online          Cancel by Staff     Doe MD, John
Online          OK                  Doe MD, John
Traditional     OK                  William MD, Liz
Online          OK                  William MD, Liz
Online          No Show             William MD, Liz
Online          Cancel by Online    William MD, Liz
Online          Cancel by Staff     William MD, Liz
```

Comment: You can accomplish this by setting up a table using doctor as a row group (use the table wizard). You will then have your data elements use booked as a category and count as your data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a matrix with Doctor as your row group, enlarge the 'data' textbox so the chart will fit into it and delete the column group.

Create your chart and then drag and drop it into the matrix.

[image]

[image]